# Does there exist a perfect and star Lindelöf space which is not separable?

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

Does there exist a perfect and star Lindelöf space which is not separable?

> A topological space in which every closed set is a $G_\delta$-set is
>   called a perfect space.
>
> A topological space $X$ is said to
>   be star Lindelöf, if for any open cover $\mathcal U$ of $X$
>   there is a Lindelöf subspace $A \subset X$ such that
>   $\operatorname{St}(A, \mathcal U)=X$.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are certainly counterexamples: all $L$-spaces will do (an $L$-space is a hereditarily Lindelöf regular space, which is not separable),  Such spaces are perfect (because open sets are $F_\sigma$, and so closed sets are $G_\delta$), and trivially star Lindelöf (as any Lindelöf space is).

[Moore](http://www.ams.org/journals/jams/2006-19-03/S0894-0347-05-00517-5/home.html) constructed an $L$-space in ZFC (I now recall).

Comment: Hadn’t seen that result; thanks for the reference!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I worked with compact $L$-spaces in the past, which are killed by MA($\omega_1)$, hence my interest in $L$-spaces and for a long time a ZFC $L$-space was open, so I was suprised when Moore came with a "real" example, when $S$-spaces need not exist in ZFC.